# Mysql query issue for multiselected field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I saved multi selected field values separate with comma in single cell for example it store values like(2,5,8).

Now I wants to fetch the records depends on single value.

For example in search if I put "2" then it should return the row which contains ("2,5,8")or("2,3")..... If i put "5" then also return the row which contains ("2,5,8")or("2,5").

Comment: FIND_IN_SET // But you should rather properly normalize this.

Comment: It works. Thank you